# XML Serialization in .NET - what's wrong with this

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml-serialization

I have xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="blah@blah.com" start="2011-10-03T15:09:30.481Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/incoming/monthly" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="2.txt" />
        <type value="D" />
        <modification value="2011-09-14T12:58:26.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxr-xr-x" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="3.txt" />
        <type value="D" />
        <modification value="2011-01-03T22:04:55.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxr-xr-x" />
      </file>
    </files>
    <result success="true" />
  </ls>
</session>
```

My representation of the following is:

```
  <XmlRoot("session", Namespace:="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0")>
    Class XMLSession
        <XmlElement("ls/files/file")>
        Public Property FileList As New List(Of XMLFile)
    End Class

 <XmlType("file")>
    Class XMLFile
        <XmlElement("filename")>
        Public Property FileName As XMLValueAttribute
        <XmlElement("type")>
        Public Property TypeName As XMLValueAttribute
        <XmlElement("permissions")>
        Public Property Permissions As XMLValueAttribute
        <XmlElement("modification")>
        Public Property ModificationDate As XMLValueAttribute
    End Class

  Class XMLValueAttribute
        <XmlAttribute("value")>
        Public Property Value As String
    End Class
```

Why is XMLSession.FileList.Count always 0. I hypothesize it has something to do with the  declaration above it but I am not sure what is wrong with it. Maybe it can't accept a path, if not, how can I do it?

Comment: Is your XML format fixed? It looks like it could use some work. For example, instead of `<file><filename value="2.txt" /></file>`, something like `<file filename="2.txt" />` would make more sense - it looks like all of your sub-elements just have the one value. If you made this change, your serialization would be a lot easier as well.

Comment: This format is generated by WinSCP so I have no control over it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't describe multiple levels of XML with a single XmlElementAttribute. You need classes for each level.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having classes for each one?

Comment: @marc_s: Your comment isn't entirely right. You don't need a class for "files" for example if you use <XMLArray("files")>. Now if only I didn't need a class for "Ls"

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to build the classes by hand, you can get the tools to do it for you:

Assuming your XML is saved in `data.xml`:

```
xsd.exe data.xml
```

This will give you `data.xsd` which defines the XML.

```
xsd.exe /l:VB /n:SomeNamespace /c data.xsd
```

This will give you a codefile `data.vb` with your types defined, which you can add to your project.

Problem with this one is that there's some kind of bug, [described here](http://satov.blogspot.com/2006/12/xsdexe-generated-classes-causing.html), which throws an error when you create a serializer around this new type. So you just need one manual tweak on the generated code, changing:

```
<XmlArrayItemAttribute("file", GetType(sessionLSFilesFile), IsNullable:=False)> _
'To
<XmlArrayItemAttribute("file", GetType(sessionLSFilesFile()), IsNullable:=False)> _
```

Comment: wish I knew about this one before I started ;-) Thanks

Comment: @Denis: it's all in the documentation.